# Problems connecting to a remote server and performing a simple db query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have set up a website with basic HTML/CSS files and would like to take that one step further and implement a database with some PHP to perform simple queries and whatnot.

My problem arose when I noticed while setting up the database and creating the PHP files that connect to the database (on my local machine), I used 'localhost' as an argument for mysql_connect. When I then went to drag and drop my newly created HTML/PHP files along with my database into FileZilla to upload the pages onto my remote server, there was a problem connecting to the database. I have a feeling that it is unhappy with the whole 'localhost' notion - yet I don't know what to change it to.

Currently, I am using this line of PHP code to connect to my remote database (which is all located in FileZilla-land).

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','Tommy','pass')
```

**Also**, as another quick question: does my remote server have its own phpMyAdmin page? And if so... how would one go about finding it? =D

I appreciate anyone who is able to assist me in my endeavors.
Thank you!!

Comment: Are you intending for the "remote" webserver to connect to the database on your local machine?  This is pretty unconventional.  It is far more typical for the "remote" webserver to connect to a database stored either on the same machine, or somewhere nearby (e.g. on the same network).  The operator of your "remote" webserver will typically provide a database server for you.

Comment: The database is being stored on the remote server, as is every other page accessing that database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log on to your database server, check the details and obtain the correct server information such as server, username and password.

Once you change the server details you shoudl be ready to rock n roll.  Edit post with the host name/server name and we may be able to find it for you.

You'll have a phpMyAdmin page where you're hosting the site. Check the membership area or cPanel.

Comment: Thank you for your post, I think I'm onto something! So do I go to a web browser and connect to the Host, and put in my username/password there to see the phpMyAdmin stuff?

Comment: No problem :) Hope it was of some use.  Once you log into the member area of the host / server, life becomes much easier :)

Answer (score 0):

You are right in that 'localhost' in mysql_connect needs to be different. 'localhost' is a textual representation of a loopback address AFAIK - it connects to the computer it is hosted on. As you have uploaded it to your server (a different computer) it is now trying to connect to a mysql server on the server host, instead of your home computer (which holds all the data).

To make this work you'd need to get your database onto the server you are now working from, OR depending on your home setup, point it to your local database.

Whether your host has MySQL/PHPMyAdmin available to you is another matter altogether. If they have MySQL it is probable but not definite that they have a phpmyadmin interface.

Contacting the server host will yield more information. If they have MySQL, it is probably as simple as getting the required details from them, and 'backing up' your SQL on your local server and uploading it to the new server (easily done with PHPMyAdmin)

**TL;DR: The database you are trying to connect to doesn't exist on the server you're connecting from.**

Comment: I realize my dilemma better now, thank you. Are you saying that my server host will tell me what to change my 'localhost' for my mysql_connect stuff?

Comment: Your server host will be able to provide you with the information you need. You will need their MySQL server address, your own username/password, and then backup your SQL from your local machine and upload it to the server host. The server address may still be localhost - it just means connect to the host that the files are stored on.

Comment: If one of these solutions answered your question, please click the associated tick to mark it correct.